# Created a layout page, but getting a parentElement null error

Tags: javascript, error, page-layout

I've created a layout page, when I run the page and look at the JavaScript console, I get a 'parentElement' null error message like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'parentElement' of null
```

There is no other error message, when I compare this to the other layout pages (which I haven't created) this error message is not displayed.

Does anyone know what causes this error message and what I could be possibly be missing in my layout page.

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: Can you provide more info? How do you get the element in your javascript code?

Comment: Hi,Yes the error message is thrown by a JS file called sp.ui.Rte.js (I file that I have not created). The my page is just a standard Layout page, but I am missing something that this JS is looking for that is causing the error, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Okay, I see. You don't have any custom js code? I have seen this in the standard pages.

Comment: Yep, it seems a standard message, not from my JS

Comment: Is the error occuring in all browsers?

Comment: Yes it is in all browsers